# FOS own form and exceptions

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I need own form to add/edit user. In my system I have employee and fos_user. Some employees have access to system.

I made big form for employee and fos_user. When I supplementing username, email and password(repeat_password) created is fos_user. But when I edited fos_user, username and email have value to base, but password is empty. After clicked "save", form is submit, and I see error:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'UPDATE fos_user SET password = ? WHERE id = ?' with params [null, 2]:
```

I know. Doctrine sees the change password, and update new value (null).

How I can disabled mapped password?

Code me class form:

```
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_BIND, function(FormEvent $event) {
      $form = $event->getForm();
      $data = $event->getData();

      $username = $form->get('username')->getData();
      $password = $form->get('password')->getData();
      $repeatPassword = $form->get('repeat_password')->getData();
      $enabled = $form->get('enabled')->getData();

      // Sprawdzamy czy ktoś chce stworzyć konto - wpisał cokolwiek w sekcji "Dostep".
      if(!empty($username) || !empty($enabled)){
        if(empty($username)){
          $form->get('username')->addError(new FormError('Brak nazwy użytkownika'));
        }

        if(!empty($password) || !empty($repeatPassword)){
          if(empty($password)){
            $form->get('password')->addError(new FormError('Brak hasła'));
          }

          if(empty($repeatPassword)){
            $form->get('repeat_password')->addError(new FormError('Brak hasła'));
          }

          if($password != $repeatPassword){
            $error = 'Hasło się różnią!';
            $form->get('password')->addError(new FormError($error));
            $form->get('repeat_password')->addError(new FormError($error));
          }
          // Zmienia text na plainPassword - zaszyfrowane hasło
          $data->setPlainPassword($password);
        }
      }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the technique I used to edit a user without having the user's password.  I expect it may work in your instance.  This example was done in an environment without FOSUserBundle but can probably be extended.

1. Create a UserEditType form class with all fields but the password field(s)
2. Assign UserEditType to a validation group other than Default
3. Configure the password length constraint to the validation group in 2.
4. Modify the edit and update actions to use UserEditType

And now users can be edited without having the password!

#### UserEditType:

```
class UserEditType extends AbstractType {
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder
                ->add('enabled', 'choice', array(
                    'choices' => array('Yes' => 'Yes', 'No' => 'No'),
                    'expanded' => true,
                    'multiple' => false,
                    'label' => 'Enabled: ',
                ))
                ->add('fname')
                ->add('sname')
                ->add('email')
                ->add('username')
                ->add('role', 'choice', array(
                    'choices' => array('ROLE_USER' => 'User', 'ROLE_ADMIN' => 'Admin'),
                    'expanded' => true,
                    'multiple' => false,
                    'label' => 'Group: ',
                ))
        ;
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Mana\ClientBundle\Entity\User',
            'validation_groups' => array('edit'),
        ));
    }
```

#### Password in User entity:

```
 * @ORM\Column(name="userpass", type="string", length=100, nullable=false)
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Password may not be empty")
 * @Assert\Length(
 *      min = "5",
 *      max = "12",
 *      minMessage = "Password must be at least 5 characters long",
 *      maxMessage = "Password cannot be longer than than 12 characters",
 *      groups = {"Default"}
 * )
```

#### Update action:

```
public function updateAction(Request $request, $id) {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $user = $em->getRepository('ManaClientBundle:User')->find($id);

    $form = $this->createForm(new UserEditType(), $user);
    $form->bind($request);
    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em->persist($user);
        $em->flush();
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('user_main', array()));
    }
    return array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        'user' => $user,
        'title' => 'Edit user',
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I went a different route. I don't know, maybe my solutions is wrong.

bulidForm:

```
...

           ->add('password', 'password', array(
                'label' => 'Password',
                'required' => false,
                'mapped' => false
            ))
            ->add('repeat_password', 'password', array(
                'label' => 'Repeat Password',
                'required' => false,
                'mapped' => false
            ))
...

$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_BIND, function(FormEvent $event) {
    $form = $event->getForm();
    $data = $event->getData();
    ...
    if(!empty($username) || !empty($enabled)){
       // check conditions
       $data->setPassword($password);
       $data->setPlainPassword($password);
    }
}
```

If I don't use setPassword() and setPlainPassword(), doesn't generate the cipher to me.